# Sitecore PDF Not Downloading

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a couple of unversioned PDFs in the media library... when I try opening them up from their URLs, it says "Layout not found". When I assign a layout (any layout), it just doesn't render anything.

I've added forcedownload=true to the media library section of the web.config... is there anything I'm missing? I thought this was supposed to download by default

```
http://testsite.org/sitecore/media%20library/pdfs/Publications/Periodicals/Test
```

The URL above basically doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't sound like a programming question to me: -1

Comment: Did you try `http://testsite.org/~/media/pdfs/Publications/Periodicals/Test.pdf`? Make sure you are using `MediaManager.GetMediaUrl()` to generate the URL links

Comment: Thank you jammy! I was foolish and it was improperly fetching the media url (it was using the item url from sitecore instead).

Comment: Always use the `MediaManager` for media items and `LinkManager` for content items when generating the URLs. I'll add it as an answer so you can mark as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links to items in the media library are usually prefixed with `/~/media/`, unless you have changed the value of `Media.MediaLinkPrefix` in config. The link should be something like:

`http://testsite.org/~/media/pdfs/Publications/Periodicals/Test.pdf`

Make sure you are generating the URLs using `MediaManager.GetMediaUrl()`

```
FileField fileField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["File Field"];
var mediaItem = new MediaItem(fileField.MediaItem);
string url = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(fileMediaItem));
```

Always use `LinkManager.GetItemUrl()` for items and `MediaManager.GetMediaUrl()` for media items to generate Sitecore URLs.

- http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/sitecore-links-with-linkmanager-and-mediamanager/
- http://corecompetency.tohams.com/index.php/linking-to-an-image-or-file-in-the-media-library/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assign a layout to media item. Make sure you add "/" prefix before the url. Ex: site/~/media/path to pdf.ashx.

Also make sure you have media files published.

Answer (score 0):

//below is the code to specify an Image URL

```
MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("Path"));
                        if (mediaItem != null)
                        {
                            imgBtn.ImageUrl = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem);
                            imgBtn.AlternateText = mediaItem.Alt;
                        }
```